# Convert string date to time.Time in golang

Tags: go

How to convert string, "Fri Sep 22 2017 15:38:22 GMT+0630" in go.

```
layout := "Fri Sep 22 2017 15:38:22 GMT+0630"
    str := "Fri Sep 23 2017 15:38:22 GMT+0630"
    t, err := time.Parse(layout, str)
    if err != nil {
        WriteError(w, err)
        return
    }
```

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> These are predefined layouts for use in Time.Format and Time.Parse. The reference time used in the layouts is the specific time:
>
> Mon Jan 2 15:04:05 MST 2006
>
> which is Unix time 1136239445. Since MST is GMT-0700, the reference time can be thought of as
>
> 01/02 03:04:05PM '06 -0700

So you need to put the date `Mon Jan 2 15:04:05 MST 2006` into the format that you are expecting, which seems like it would be:

```
layout := "Mon Jan 02 2006 15:04:05 GMT-0700"
```

https://play.golang.org/p/I9dRT5JdOA

Comment: Thanks Dave. I don't know that MST is GMT-0700. It is working now.